# Save org-babel output with org-attach

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, r

I am using org-babel to write R code in Emacs org-mode. Here's an example:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC R :session *R* :results output graphics :width 5 :height 5

data(AirPassengers)
AP <- AirPassengers
plot(AP)

#+END_SRC
```

What I would like to do with this, is to add a header argument that tells babel to save the outfile using `org-attach`, so that I don't have to specify a filename or directory.

There used to be a way to do this with `org-R` using the header args `#+R outfile:"png"`. But this seems to be depricated in `org-babel`... Any ideas?